# How to remove localStorage after timeout of a snackbar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuetify.js

[image]

I'm using this Vuetify `<v-snackbar`, I triggered it base on values that I stored in localStorage.

## /create

After I created my object

Ex.

```
localStorage.setItem('alert', true)
localStorage.setItem('alertColor', 'green')
localStorage.setItem('alertMessage', this.form.values.name + ' - created successfully!')
```

With these codes

```
<v-snackbar timeout="2000" v-model="alert" absolute top :color="alertColor" outlined right>
    <strong>
        {{ alertMessage }}
    </strong>
</v-snackbar>
```

---

## /index (list)

I checked localStorage and show a proper alert ***message*** + ***color***.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            alert: localStorage.getItem('alert'),
            alertColor: localStorage.getItem('alertColor'),
            alertMessage: localStorage.getItem('alertMessage'),
```

---

After `timeout="2000"` my alert hide, I would like to remove my localStorage so when I refresh the page, I don't see that same alert again.

```
localStorage.removeItem('alert')
localStorage.removeItem('alertColor')
localStorage.removeItem('alertMessage')
```

Comment: I was in /create , and redirect to index(list) page.

Comment: Use sessionStorage then

Comment: Why does it matter if I am clear on logOut anyway?

Comment: How can I doSomething on hide of my snack-bar ?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119737/vuetify-snackbar-leave-event

Comment: @Raffael : Not really. I added those 3 line into a fn(), call it mounted()  ... I got it working for now. I want to see a cleaner way if anyone know.

Comment: Why do you have to wait for the timeout before removing the items from local storage? Just remove the items after you have retrieved them for the alert.

Comment: Which part of codes I should do please add your answer so I can clearly understand your envision.

Answer (score 4):

You can watch your reactive data `alert`. When the `alert` data is false, then you can clear the localStorage

```js
export default {
 data(){
   return {
     alert: false
   }
 },
 watch:{
  alert(newValue){
     if(!newValue) clearLocalStorage()
  }
 },
 methods:{
   clearLocalStorage(){
     localStorage.removeItem('alert')
     localStorage.removeItem('alertColor')
     localStorage.removeItem('alertMessage')
   }
 }

}
```